# Working around INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-version

My Android application has to be upgraded/downgraded automatically according to the version of a PC application that runs in parallel with it. The app easily upgrades itself using an Intent that launch the Package installer. The problem appears when it tries to downgrade itself. I got the message INSTALLED_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE when working in Debug with Eclipse and a "fail" message when the downgrade is done automatically. This occurs since I switch to 4.2.2.

I know that a downgrade is easy if we simply uninstall the app then re-install the older version. But I want it to be done automatically and the app cannot uninstall it then after re-install itself. (But if we can chain Intents before starting them?????)

So my question is simple: is it possible to deactivate this "feature"?

Comment: You are welcome to build your own ROM mod that somehow works around this.

Comment: I understand by your comment that there is no way to perform what I want...

Comment: Is there a way to call a chained intent? First step: uninstall, second step: install new .apk?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to allow for downgrading of apps on a standard Android device, other than via the uninstall-and-reinstall route as you mention. If this is some sort of kiosk device, where you control the environment, you could have the uninstall/reinstall work be done by some separate app, but that would be annoying for an ordinary consumer device.